# implementing the macro for while loop

Tags: c++, c

Can the below while loop be implemented in a macro??

```
while (x < 0.5)
 {
 count++;
 x = x *2;
 }
```

x is a very small no. in fractions

Comment: Seriously, JavaScript and ASP.NET? **Is this a joke**?

Comment: Any program you can write can be implemented in a C or C++ (which is it? you tagged both but it's probably only one of them) macro, as @Luchian Grigore's answer expresses. Perhaps you could format a better question that addresses your need, rather than an overly vague question with overly excessive use of language tags.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes this is a pointer.

Comment: I am new to this site... just added other language tags to get more visibility.. thats it only

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
#define MYMACRO \
while (x < 0.5)\
\
 {\
 count++;\
\
 x = x *2;\
\
 }
```

I even kept your formatting ;)

Comment: I like the comment that question is vague.. rather than this answer.. any child can write this way. I was looking for some other way of implementing the same logic without the use of while loop.